Can we no longer predict the behavior of a particle with a definite position?
This might be a really dumb question as I am just learning QM for the first time.
Shankar says that physically interesting wavefunctions can be normalized to a unit $L^2$-norm:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\psi(x)|^{2}\mathrm{d}x = 1$$
and these functions are the same ones that can be written as a linear combination of states of definite energy. And therefore, these are the main functions that satisfy the Schrödinger equation.
But what about the Dirac delta function? It is not square-integrable, and when I try to plug it into the Schrödinger equation, it looks like it doesn't satisfy it. But don't all wavefunctions collapse into a Dirac delta function once their position is measured? Does this mean that if we know the position of a particle, then we are unable to say anything about what will happen to it over time?

If you could make an infinitely-precise position measurement, it would collapse to the Dirac delta, but you can't because the particle also has momentum and there exists an uncertainty relation between position and momentum (the operators don't commute).

There does not exist any physical device that can measure a quantum(*) at a dimensionless point. All measuring devices have finite sizes. This leads to measurement uncertainties in the positions of the quanta. Therefore, a wave function never "collapses" to a Dirac delta function. However, if we know the distribution of such a quantum at a given time and we have the equations of motion that such a field must obey, then we can predict how the distribution will propagate.
(*) I'm using the word "quantum" instead of "particle" to avoid the confusion that there physically is a particle occupying a dimensionless point.

First let's consider the situation, abstracting from the real-life limits of measurements.
The problem with Dirac delta is that ideally, it should describe a probability density. Then it would be integrable (not square-integrable, but this is not needed now) and behave as one would expect. And if you consider a sequence of experiments of measuring a particle's position, with the uncertainty of the measurement tending to zero, you'll get, for the resulting states${}^\dagger$, say, $\psi_n(\vec r),$ of each such measurement $n$, a sequence of probability distributions $|\psi_n(\vec r)|^2$ that tend to Dirac delta.
Now you can see where the non-square-integrability problem comes: when speaking of a Dirac-delta state we are trying to describe the state itself, rather than its modulus squared, with Dirac delta. This makes sense, because then we have a finite wavefunction in, say, momentum representation—where the ordinary sequence of ever-narrowing position distributions would yield an identical zero for the limit wavefunction in momentum representation. But by doing this we end up with the split between normalizable and non-normalizable states.
Now we can consider your "Shankar says that physically interesting wavefunctions...". All the limit wavefunctions we've just been discussing are just that: limit states that are never achievable in reality (in finite time). This is why they are not "physically interesting". They are useful for the theory though.

${}^\dagger$Assuming for simplicity that they are pure, so that we can describe them by wavefunctions.

The equations of motion of quantum theory, such as the Schrodinger equation, don't include collapse and aren't compatible with it. Some physicists have attempted to modify those equations to include collapse, see this review
https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.14969
Such theories don't currently reproduce the predictions of relativistic quantum field theories, which are the vast bulk of predictions made by quantum theory
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
If we don't modify the equations of quantum theory to include collapse then a measurement is just an interaction that produces a record we can copy and examine of some property of a system. When you try to copy information out of a system interference is suppressed: this is called decoherence
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
The objects you see around you in everyday life have information copied out of them on scales of space and time a lot smaller than those over which they change significantly and as a result interference is very heavily suppressed for them. Decoherence selects a set of non-interfering states, each of which approximately obeys the laws of classical physics, which tend to be highly peaked in both position and momentum on the scales of everyday life but they aren't delta functions. Since decoherence theories have been experimentally tested and have not found wanting there is no reason to think that delta function position states or collapse exist in reality.
